# servlet 404 found error when using html form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I searched a lot but was not able to resolve it, need help.

I am trying to request something to a servlet which is under

> project/src/com/servletfile.java

from a jsp file which is under

> project/web-inf/jspfile.jsp

```
<form action="servletfile.java" >
      <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> <br/><br/>
</form>
```

below is the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletfile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.servletfile</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletfile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletfile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

however when i click on submit it says file not found.

Comment: What do you think `<form action="servletfile.java"` will do? Why do you think so?

Comment: missed the close bracket in form.. but still it did not work. tried /servletfile.java

Comment: Bhavik, @SotiriosDelimanolis's point is, why use `.java` in action. If you observe your web.xml, you will see that .java `<servlet-class>` mapping of `.java` ( i.e., the servlet) to the `<url-pattern>` you provide in the `action` attribute of the form is taken care of using `<servlet-name>`

Comment: okay.. thanks for the explaining that part. however even though i remove it , it doesnt work. the browser link checks under localhost:8080/file but shouldnt it be checking under localhost:8080/app/file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your this line of html form tag as below, removed `.java`:

```
<form action="servletfile">
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<form action="servletfile.java"
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> <br/><br/>
 </form>
```

to

```
 <form action="servletfile"
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> <br/><br/>
 </form>
```

you are missing the basics.

Comment: tried but still says 404 below is the browser link http://localhost:8080/servletfile.java?submit=submit

Comment: @BhavikPatel it should be `http://localhost:8080/yourAppContext/servletfile` where `yourAppContext` is the context root of your app.. you are doing something wrong

Comment: when i pull the jsp page it is http://localhost:8080/ToExcelWeb/jspfile.jsp but when I click the submit its  localhost:8080/servletfile.java?submit=submit –

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it ..super silly mistake

had a radio button input and after that i wrote the form, but when placed the radio button inside the form tag it resovled

changed

```
Test <input type"radio" name="test"/>
<form action="servletfile"
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> <br/><br/>
 </form>
```

to

```
     <form action="servletfile" >
        Test <input type"radio" name="test"/>
         <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" /> <br/><br/>
    </form>
```